# MSVC DLL exporting class that inherits from template cause LNK2005 already defined error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, dll, lnk2005

I've been tracking an error in a huge project for 3 days and finally get a minimum reproducable example. I want to share this problem and ask some questions on the weird behavior of Visual Studio.

When you export a class that inherits from a instantiated template class , like

```cxx
class __declspec(dllexport) classA : public Template<double>{}
```

MSVC will also export the instantiated template class `Template<double>` in DLL.

If the consumer include `"template.h"` in his code then instantiate a `Template<double>`, qnd at the same time, link to the above DLL, he will get two definition of `Template<double>`, which causes **LNK2005** and **LNK1169** error. This problem is discussed in [Microsoft DLL export and C++ templates](http://www.codesynthesis.com/%7Eboris/blog/2010/01/18/dll-export-cxx-templates/).

Here is a minimum reproducable example of this problem (Full code is [here](https://github.com/flm8620/MSVC_export_template_bug)):

```cxx
// ----------- Project AA ------------
// aa/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(AA)
add_library(AA SHARED classA.cpp)                          //(1)
set_target_properties(AA PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DBUILD_AA")

// aa/config.h
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN32
#  ifdef BUILD_AA
#    define AA_API __declspec( dllexport )
#  else
#    define AA_API __declspec( dllimport )
#  endif
#else
#   define AA_API
#endif

// aa/template.h
#pragma once
template<class T>
class Template {
public:
    Template() {}
};

//  aa/classA.h
#pragma once
#include "config.h"
#include "template.h"
class AA_API classA : public Template<double> {         //(2)
public:
    int fun();
};

// aa/classA.cpp
#include "classA.h"
int classA::funA(){return 123;}

// ----------- Project Main ----------
//CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(Main)
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
add_subdirectory(aa)
add_executable(Main main.cpp test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Main PUBLIC AA)

// main.cpp
#include "aa/classA.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    Template<double> a;                                //(3)
    //classA aa;                                       //(4)
    //std::cout << aa.funA() << std::endl;             //(5)
    return 0;
}

// test.cpp
#include "aa/template.h"
class classB {
    Template<double> t;
};
class classC : public Template<double> {};

void fun() {
    Template<double> b;                               //(6)
    //class classB;                                   //(7)
    //class classC;                                   //(8)
}
```

I compile the code in VS2015 Debug mode, it gives multiply defined error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: AA, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  classA.cpp
1>  AA.vcxproj -> D:\sandbox\build\aa\Debug\AA.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Main, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
2>  main.cpp
2>AA.lib(AA.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl Template<double>::Template<double>(void)" (??0?$Template@N@@QEAA@XZ) already defined in test.obj
2>D:\sandbox\build\Debug\Main.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If I do **ONE OF** the following changes, there will be no error:

1. Change to Release mode
2. Remove `AA_API` at `(2)` and change link mode to STATIC at `(1)`
3. Comment `(3)` and uncomment `(4)` and `(5)`
4. Comment `(6)` and uncomment `(7)` and `(8)`
5. Compile in Linux by gcc
6. Change project parameter in VS : add `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` to Linker for project Main

## Question:

Why changes 1,2,3,4 and 5 work ? I think it's so weird that 3 and 4 can work.

How to solve this problem properly in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Was this problem ever reported to microsoft? Looks like a really horrible problem with no good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem recently. I managed to fix it finally so I will share my knowledge.

**Source of the problem:**

The template is instantiated multiple times. That is because you use implicit instantiation. Once when you declare class AA_API classA and once in the main when you declare Template< double > a; in main.

This means you will have  more than one definitions for template.

- 1, I am not sure why it is working in release mode (consider it to the lack of my deep knowledge with templates)
- 2,3,4,when you get rid of any of the implicit template instantiation, you get rid of the multiple definitions
- 5, maybe gcc does the instantiation differently, or there is a force multiply flag somewhere... I don't know
- 6, This does not solve your problem, it just forces to accept the multiple instants.

**Solution:**

Explicit instantiation.

```
// aa/template.h
#pragma once
template<class T>
class Template {
public:
    Template() {}
};
template class Template<double>;  // Put this line after your template class.
```

Note: if the template class is in a different project, you need to export the instantiation.

I hope this will sort out your problem. It has fixed mine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. But explicit instantiation in header file doesn't solve my problem. If `template.h` is included in multiple cpp, there will be multiple definitions.

Comment: If I add this explicit instantiation in header file, the step 4 no longer solves my problem.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the nature of your problem is slightly different. Unfortunately I don't know the exact explanation, but if I replace the constructor in your Template class with the default constructor it builds.
You don't even need any explicit instantiation.